RStudio Cannot Knit

I switched from an Intel Mac to an M3-pro Mac a couple of weeks ago. I migrated everything from the old laptop to this new one, including R and RStudio. Knitting worked perfectly fine on the old laptop, and, however, does not work at all on my new laptop.
I keep getting the error message as shown in the image attached. I have tried reinstalling R and RStudio but neither works.
Could somebody please help look at this? I couldn't find anything related to this error message online.
output file: Homoework-8.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
 \tl_trim_spaces:e
{__keys_remove_equals:n { }}
l.266 \edef
\Gin@driver{\Gin@driver}
Error: LaTeX failed to compile Homoework-8.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Homoework-8.log for more info.
Execution halted

